# SQL - Create a constraint that involves data from other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

It's my first time using SQL Developer and I'm having issues with a concret constraint. I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Act
   (IDAct VARCHAR2(15),
   DNIref VARCHAR2(15),
   matchDay DATE,
   stadium VARCHAR2(30),
   CONSTRAINT Act_PK PRIMARY KEY(IDAct),
   CONSTRAINT Act_FK_Referee FOREIGN KEY(DNIref) REFERENCES Referee(DNI),
   CONSTRAINT Act_FK_Match FOREIGN KEY(matchDay, stadium) REFERENCES Match(matchDay, stadium)
);

CREATE TABLE Match(
   matchDay Date,
   stadium VARCHAR2(30),
   dayHour TIMESTAMP,
   DNIref VARCHAR2(15),
   CIFVisitor VARCHAR2(15),
   CIFHome VARCHAR2(15),
   CONSTRAINT Match_CK_HV CHECK (CIFVisitor <> CIFHome),
   CONSTRAINT Match_PK PRIMARY KEY(matchDay, stadium),
   CONSTRAINT Match_FK_Referee FOREIGN KEY(DNIref) REFERENCES Referee(DNI),
   CONSTRAINT Match_FK_Visitor FOREIGN KEY(CIFVisitor)
      REFERENCES Team(CIF),
   CONSTRAINT Match_FK_Home FOREIGN KEY(CIFHome)
      REFERENCES Team(CIF)
);
```

And I've been asked to add the following constraint:

> The referee that takes minutes of an incident act, must referee the match associated to the act.

Or something like that (English is not my mother tongue and I'm trying to do my best). How can I do that with an ALTER TABLE Act ADD CONSTRAINT sentence? Is there any other way? Thanks a lot in advance (this is my first post).

Comment: Constraint can refer only to the current table columns and only to the currant row values. If you need to refer to another rows or tables then use trigger logic.

Comment: *`CONSTRAINT Match_PK PRIMARY KEY(matchDay, stadium)`* - do you think that 2 matches per day on the same staduim is impossible? Use synthetic PR and refer an act to the match. In this case `Act.DNIref` column is excess and must be removed.

Comment: Trigger logic, got it. Thanks Akina. And about the impossibility of celebrating more than one match per day in the same stadium, our teacher told us to implement it that way, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Akina - in English (and perhaps in the SQL dialects you are more familiar with), `date` actually means "date" (the common sense of the word). In Oracle it doesn't - oracle `date` data type always includes a time-of-day. So your comment about multiple matches on the same stadium on the same "date" doesn't make sense. If you are not familiar with Oracle, let people who are help the posters who have Oracle questions, and feel free to help those who ask questions in your area of specialty.

Comment: @amelero - What does "referee that takes minutes of an incident act" mean? How is that related to / reflected in the two tables you posted? In any case, if "incidents" are details of a match, and they are recorded in the `act` table, then the `act` table should only have a foreign key reference to the `match` table, but otherwise it shouldn't repeat any of the information from the parent table. Why do you have `referee` in the `act` table at all, when the referee is completely determined by the match (identified by stadium and date)?

Comment: As it currently stands your `act` table serves no purpose. It consists of the FK to `match` table and a column already in `match`. The issue is making sure those columns are the same. Other that It also contains an apparently unless PK of its own.  Just drop the table `act`, if reference to it is absolutely required recreate it as a *view* on `match`.